# Phrase for ending animal's suffering

Tags: phrases

Is there a phrase for situation where animal is suffering, and then someone kills it because that person don't want that animal to suffer anymore

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, these 'reverse duplicates' are hard to call. Certainly the/the best answer is given in the prior thread.

Comment: We often say a wounded animal is 'put out of its misery'.

Answer (score 2):

The comments on the other question don't seem to include any mention of the euphemisms *put to sleep* and *put down*, often used of animals, at least in British English.